# Getting Array from MySQL Column

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

I'm storing an array of comma separated values in my database in a column called `line_services`. The data in the column looks like `1,1,1,1,0,0,0` and I have a prepared statement where I bind the results of this column to the variable `$line_services`. In this prepared statement I have the following code after my fetch.

```
foreach(explode(',', $line_services) as $lineservices) {
    if ($lineservices == '1') {
        strtolower(str_replace('','_',$service_name.'_total')) = ((($service_tax / 100) * $service_cost) + 80.00) * $line_artwork_hours;  //1 hour
    }
    if ($lineservices == '2') {
        strtolower(str_replace('','_',$service_name.'_total')) = ((($service_tax / 100) * $material_cost) + $material_cost) * $line_product_sqft; //2 sq ft
    }    
    if ($lineservices == '3') {
        strtolower(str_replace('','_',$service_name.'_total')) = (($service_tax / 100) * ($line_L + $line_W)) + ($line_L + $line_W); //3 linear
    } 
    if ($lineservices == '4') {
        strtolower(str_replace('','_',$service_name.'_total')) = (($service_tax / 100) * (($line_L + $line_W) * 2) * .75) + (($line_L + $line_W) * 2) * .75; //4 linear
    } 
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Can't use function return value in write context

When I do a `var_dump` on `$line_services` it is coming up `NULL` even though there is data in the column. The line_services column in the database is a varchar if that makes any difference.

Comment: please add the rest of your code for  "When I do a var_dump on $line_services it is coming up NULL"

Comment: Did you give up or what???

Comment: I didn't give up. Removed the strtolower and it worked. I didn't end up using variable variables just straight up arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are trying for a [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)?  Rarely if ever a good idea, but you can use the curly syntax:

```
${strtolower(str_replace('','_',$service_name.'_total'))} = 'whatever';
```

Consider using an array instead:

```
$total[$service_name] = 'whatever';
```

Comment: didn't end up using the variable variable but the strtolower was causing the big issue. I used a straight up array. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are using an assignment to strtolower, and you can't do this. Check your code:

```
strtolower(str_replace(...)) = ...;
```

That doesn't make any sense. What are you trying to do? You are not assigning the result of `(($service_tax / 100) * ($line_L + $line_W)) + ($line_L + $line_W)` (for example) to any variable.

Comment: All variables are defined in my prepared statement

Comment: The goal is to have the results of the math forumula get stored in the variable `$service_name_total`

Comment: this is a good point, I did not know that you can't use strtolower

Comment: I haven't said that you can't use strtolower, I have said that the way you were using it was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you are overwriting your variable in you foreach.

```
foreach(explode(',', $line_services) as $lineservices)
```

Switch this to:

```
foreach(explode(',', $line_services) as $lineservice)
```

Second of all, what are you expecting to happen here?

```
strtolower(str_replace('','_',$service_name.'_total')) = ((($service_tax / 100) * $service_cost) + 80.00) * $line_artwork_hours;
```

You are trying to assign a value to the strtolower function?

Comment: `$line_services` != `$lineservices`. There's no overwriting.

Comment: I have a service called Graphic Design for example so the purpose of `strtolower` and `str_replace` is to ensure that all variables come in as variable_name rather than Variable Name.

Comment: The goal is to have the results of the math formula get stored in the variable `$service_name_total`